# NSArray assignment

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have two viewControllers and one has to pass an array to another, but on receiving side i am always getting count 0. here is what i did

### classA.h

```
Class A : UIViewController
{
@private 
    NSMutableArray *_array;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain ) NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

### classA.m

```
@implementation

@synthesis array =_array;

-(void) nowShow
{
    int objCount = [ _array count ];   // This is always coming as 0 though i tried various ways (listed below )
}
@end
```

### classB.m

```
-(void) method:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *msgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i <objCount; i++ ){
        unsigned int idMsg = msgId[i];
        [msgArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:idMsg]];
    }

    classA *classAController = [[classA alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];    

    //[ classAController.array arrayWithObject
    //[classAController.array addObjectsFromArray:msgArray];
    [ classAController.array initWithArray:msgArray];
    //[classAController.array setArray:moveArray];
    [self presentModalViewController:classAController animated:YES];
}
```

Any suggestion guys

Comment: Indent all lines of code with four spaces to format it as code. You can also use the "101\n010" button on a new line to insert spaces. Click the "edit" link and do this now.

Comment: A number of identifiers used in `B -(void)method:(id)` aren't defined in the sample. Are `objCount` and `msgId` instance variables?

Comment: What is the overall goal? This design might be flawed to begin with.

Comment: Yes design it flawed and it's existing product. Now my goal is to pass any array to another view controller when initializing the viewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call any `init` method unless it's immediately after calling `alloc`.

With properties, all you need to use is assignment:

```
classAController.array = msgArray;
```

Answer (score 2):

The keyword should be @synthesize not @synthesis

edit: also you want to synthesize the property "array", not the instance variable _array

Comment: `@synthesize array = _array;` should be fine. It directs the compiler to use the instance variable `_array` for the property `array` in the accessors.

Comment: Are you sure about this: @synthesize array = _array;  ?  I have never seen syntax like that on a @synthesize macro before.  Interesting.

Comment: It was type mistake, it's actually @synthesize

Comment: yup, I'm sure: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW11